# Create association between marketing list and contact entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am using php to interact with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 using library [located here](https://code.google.com/p/php-dynamics-crm-2011/downloads/list).

Can anyone tell me how to add contact to marketing list for a given list.

```
static::$contact = new \DynamicsCRM2011_Contact(static::get_connector());
static::$contact->contactid = trim($contact_id);
static::$list = new \DynamicsCRM2011_List(static::get_connector());
static::$list->__set('listname', 'testlist');
static::$list->__set('listcontact_association', static::$contact);
$list_info = static::get_connector()->create(static::$list);
```

Comment: My code did not work at all.if you have any sample code that will help.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work you should build correct Soap Request. You can take all needed information from following article - http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/11/add-entity-member-to-marketing-list-in.html